# Rails 3: Fetching a pre-generated value from a related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app where the client will provide a list of pre-generated codes. When someone purchases a license, one of these codes will be served up.

There is a `Product` model that `has_many :codes`, and a `Code` model that `belongs_to :product`. The code model has a `state` which is either "assigned" or "unassigned".

How do I ensure that each code gets used only once, even if multiple processes are trying to fetch it? In the bad old days, I would lock the record, and if I couldn't lock it, move to the next one, but I'm not even sure I can do something like that in Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "bad old days" where ACID existed are still today. Read more on Rails/AR's locking [on railsguides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#locking-records-for-update).

```
Item.transaction do
  i = Item.lock("LOCK IN SHARE MODE").find(id)
  # get rollin
  i.save!
end
```